# Angular how to retrieve all jsonResponse based on key value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a sample jsonResponse. I was wondering how to obtain the values of each "issue_date" and storing it in an ArrayList in angular.

```
[
   {
      "abc":103.2,
      "metadata":[
         {
            "value":"",
            "key":"external_status"
         },
         {
            "value":"2020-08-13",
            "key":"due_date"
         }
      ],
      "test": "someValue",
      "issue_date":"2020-07-23"
   },
   {
      "abc":104.2,
      "metadata":[
         {
            "value":"",
            "key":"external_status"
         },
         {
            "value":"2020-07-13",
            "key":"due_date"
         }
      ],
      "test": "someValue",
      "issue_date":"2020-06-23"
   },
   {
      "abc":222.2,
      "metadata":[
         {
            "value":"",
            "key":"external_status"
         },
         {
            "value":"2020-06-13",
            "key":"due_date"
         }
      ],
      "test": "someValue",
      "issue_date":"2020-05-23"
   }
]
```

In the component, I have called an API get request to obtain these values. I store this response into an arraylist. I want to create another arraylist to store all the values for "Issue_Date'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `.map()` the values out:

```
const issueDates: string[] = yourJSON.map(item => item.issue_date);
```

.map() reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map